# Error: Cannot send data if the connection is not in the 'Connected' State. Why my signalR connection isn't working?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, signalr

I'm trying to implement SignalR on my project. Here is the code of my Index.cshtml where I start the connection and then I get data from URL. Everytime I run my code I get the error !"Error: Cannot send data if the connection is not in the 'Connected' State" and it doesn't show the map like it used to before I installed the SignalR.

```
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/myHub").build();

connection.on("ReDesignMap", function () {
//script que retorna todas as ignições presentes na base de dados 
  //$(document).ready(function ()    {

$.get( "/api/IgnicoesAPI", function( data ) {
  $.each(data, function (i, item) {  
                //janela de informação de cada marcador 
    var estado = "em avaliação"
    var infowindow = '<div id="content" style="hight:700px; width:500px">' +
                    '<div id="siteNotice">' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div id="bodyContent">' +
                    '<p><b>Avaliação da Ocorrência:</b></p>' +
                    // iterar todas as ocorrencias para tirar delas as imagens
                    //$.each(item.ListaOcorrencias, function (f, foto) {
                    //    '<img src="https://wpde.com/resources/media/83f69602-210f-4ad1-bad0-bd5cf19470c7-large16x9_MARIONWOODSFIRE2.jpeg?1553519933510https://wpde.com/resources/media/83f69602-210f-4ad1-bad0-bd5cf19470c7-large16x9_MARIONWOODSFIRE2.jpeg?1553519933510" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow" style="width:70px; height:60px" hspace="4">' +

                    //        });


                            '<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b6/Controlled_burn_to_restore_mountain_longleaf_pine_in_northwest_Georgia_-_170317-FS-Chattahoochee-Oconee-SB-062_%2833575304935%29.jpg" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow" style="width:70px; height:60px" hspace="4">' +
                        '<img src="https://b50ym1n8ryw31pmkr4671ui1c64-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/11/files/2016/09/wildfire_px-1024x500.png" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(3)" class="hover-shadow" style="width:70px; height:60px" hspace="4">' +        
                    //
                    '<p></p>' +
                    '<div class="button-holder">' +
                    '<a href="#slider-image-1" class="slider-change"></a>' +
                    '<a href="#slider-image-2" class="slider-change"></a>' +
                    '<a href="#slider-image-3" class="slider-change"></a>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div> ' + 
                    '<p id="estadoP"> Estado: '+ estado +'</p>'+
                    '<button id="aceite" onclick="aceite()" style="background-color:#4CAF50;border: none;color: white;padding: 5px 12px;text-align: center;display: inline-block;font-size: 16px; box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19); margin:5px;">Aceitar</button>' +
                    '<button id="recusado" onclick="recusado()" style="background-color:#f44336;border: none;color: white;padding: 5px 12px;text-align: center;display: inline-block;font-size: 16px; box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);margin:5px;" >Recusar</button>' +
                    '<button id="concluido" onclick="concluido()" style="background-color:#008CBA;border: none;color: white;padding: 5px 12px;text-align: center;display: inline-block;font-size: 16px; box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);margin:5px;" > Concluído</button>' +
                    '</div>';

                //definição do icon para o marcador
   var ignicao = L.icon({
                    iconUrl: 'https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basicolor-signs-warnings/24/186_fire-512.png',
                    iconSize: [35, 35], // size of the icon
                });
                //colocar um marcador no mapa de acordo com a latitude e longitude fornecidas 
                var marker = new L.marker([item.latitude, item.longitude], { icon: ignicao })
                    .bindPopup(infowindow)
                    .on('click', onClick)
                    .addTo(map);
                //adiciona marador ao mapa
      $('#json map').append(marker);


            }); // fim do 'for each'
   });


 });

connection.invoke("ReDesignMap").catch(function (err) {
 return console.error(err.toString());
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to connect to signalr server first.

```
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/myHub").build();
await connection.start();

connection.invoke("ReDesignMap").catch(function (err) {
  return console.error(err.toString());
});

// or if you don't use async/await style
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/myHub").build();
connection.start().then(() => {
  connection.invoke("ReDesignMap").catch(function (err) {
    return console.error(err.toString());
  });
}
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-3.1 for a complete example.

Comment: when I added "await connection.start()" it gives me an error saying "await is only valid in async function". And then I tried following the example and add just `connection.start().catch(function (err) {return console.error(err.toString());});` and gives me the same error that I had before " Error: Cannot send data if the connection is not in the 'Connected' State."

Comment: If you're in plain javascript simply use the `then(() => {})` style. I've updated the example.

Answer (score -1):

you must delay with method `setTimeout` like under

```
setTimeout(function () {
       connection.invoke("ReDesignMap");
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Why is this needed? What's the benefit of this approach over the accepted answer?